# VBA: copy data from website into excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a VBA code that selects info from drop-down menus on a government website and then submits the query. The requested data then opens up in another IE page. I am trying to copy this data into excel; however, I am unable to do so. 
My code currently copies the text on the first IE page that contains the drop-down menus. The government website is: http://www.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/Eng/wt-ow/Pages/FINDAT.aspx

I have look all over the internet for a solution but nothing seems to work...

Here is my code:

```
Sub GetOsfiFinancialData()

Dim UrlAddress As String
UrlAddress = "http://ws1.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/FINDAT/DTIBanks.aspx?T=0&LANG=E"

Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
With ie
    .Silent = True
    .Visible = False
    .navigate UrlAddress
End With

Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

'Select Bank
ie.document.getElementById("DTIWebPartManager_gwpDTIBankControl1_DTIBankControl1_institutionTypeCriteria_institutionsDropDownList").Value = Z005

'open window with financial data
Dim objButton
Set objButton = ie.document.getElementById("DTIWebPartManager_gwpDTIBankControl1_DTIBankControl1_submitButton")
objButton.Focus
objButton.Click

'select new pop-up window
marker = 0
Set objshell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objshell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_title = objshell.Windows(x).document.Title

    If my_title Like "Consolidated Monthly Balance Sheet" & "*" Then 'compare to find if the desired web page is already open
        Set ie = objshell.Windows(x)
        marker = 1
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next

Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim tables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim table As MSHTML.HTMLTable
Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject

Set doc = ie.document
Set tables = doc.getElementsByTagName("body")
Set table = tables(0)
Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject

'paste in sheets
Dim test
Set test = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Test")
clipboard.SetText table.outerHTML
clipboard.PutInClipboard
test.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
clipboard.Clear

MsgBox ("Task Completed")

End Sub
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what error or misbehavior are you getting?

Comment: Which bank are you trying to select? And what is the data you are hoping to get back?

Comment: @Yuca: When I run the code it copies the query page and not the data output that appears in the pop-up window.

Comment: @Qharr: for now, I am trying to copy the data of Total All Banks. I want to copy the output that appears in the pop up window in excel.

Comment: what is Z005 ? It appears to be a variable but I can't see it assigned anywhere.

Comment: It is the option for the dropdown list to select Total All Banks.

Comment: If it is a string it should be in "" ?

Answer (score 1):

You were using the current test with `document.Title`. I found that `For Each` of all windows looking for the full title worked in combination with copy pasting the pop-up window outerHTML. No additional wait time was required.

Inside the `For Each Loop`, after you reset the IE instance to the new window, you can obtain the new URL with `ie.document.url`. As you already have the data loaded you might as well just copy paste it straight away in my opinion.

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetOsfiFinancialData()
    Dim UrlAddress As String, objButton, ie As Object
    UrlAddress = "http://ws1.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/FINDAT/DTIBanks.aspx?T=0&LANG=E"
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With ie
        .Silent = True
        .Visible = False
        .navigate UrlAddress

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.getElementById("DTIWebPartManager_gwpDTIBankControl1_DTIBankControl1_institutionTypeCriteria_institutionsDropDownList").Value = "Z005"

        Set objButton = .document.getElementById("DTIWebPartManager_gwpDTIBankControl1_DTIBankControl1_submitButton")
        objButton.Focus
        objButton.Click

        Dim objShellWindows As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows, currentWindow As IWebBrowser2

        For Each currentWindow In objShellWindows
            If currentWindow.document.Title = "Consolidated Monthly Balance Sheet - Banks, Trust and Loan" Then
                Set ie = currentWindow
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        Dim clipboard As Object
        Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        clipboard.SetText ie.document.body.outerHTML
        clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft Internet Controls

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to get into all the stuff about controlling one browser from another, but I think you can figure that part out, especially since you made some great progress on this already.  Get URL#2 from URL#1, like you are doing, but with some better data controls around it, and then do this...

```
Option Explicit
Sub Web_Table_Option_One()
    Dim xml    As Object
    Dim html   As Object
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim result As String
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lngTable As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ActRw As Long
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    With xml
        .Open "GET", "http://ws1.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/Temp/2f40b7ef-d024-4eca-a8a3-fb82153efafaFinancialData.aspx", False
        .send
    End With
    result = xml.responseText
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = result
    Set objTable = html.getElementsByTagName("Table")
    For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
        For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
            For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
            Next lngCol
        Next lngRow
        ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
    Next lngTable
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try this.